# How to make CastleWindsor create a new instance when Resolve is called

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have the following code:

```
public interface IService { }
public class MyService : IService { }
```

and a test method

```
[Test]
public void T1()
{
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

    container.Register(Component.For<IService>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyService>());

    var s1 = container.Resolve<IService>();
    var s2 = container.Resolve<IService>();
    Assert.AreNotSame(s1, s2);
}
```

What should I change for the test to pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the lifestyle to `Transient`:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IService>()
             .ImplementedBy<MyService>()
             .LifeStyle.Transient
);
```

The default lifestyle is `Singleton` and that's why you see the same instance.

Comment: Yes, one would think that the **Transient** lifestyle would do such thing. But it does nothing. I have dug inside the Windsor container a lot. Check the source code and you'll note exactly that.

Comment: @Paulo Santos: Sorry, but the test passes. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: The current api is different now, it should be LifeStyleTransient() instead of LifeStyle.Transient. See http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx . It wouldn't let me edit because it was less than 6 characters